# Cannot Reset MFA for External User

Tags: mfa

We enabled MFA for external users after the external users had already been created and logged in.

I am trying to login now as a test external user account to experience cloud.  As soon as I enter my password, I am asked to provide a code from my authenticator app.  But 2FA was never configured for this account.  As a system admin, when I view the user's page in Setup, there is no indication that 2FA was enabled and, therefore, no way to reset it.[image]

This external user appears to be stuck and cannot login nor an their MFA be set/reset.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Can you use the "Having Trouble?" link when prompted?

Comment: There is no such link on the 2FA challenge page.